# Advice on font for a "Portfolio" website

Tags: typography

I am working on my portfolio website now, and I am trying to pick a font but I have no idea which one to use. All I know is that I am looking for a Sans-Serif font that leaves kind of a "raw" feeling, and by "raw", I mean something that inspire honesty, dynamism and simplicity ... Any suggestion is welcome.

The overall design is minimalistic ...

Comment: what says "honesty, dynamism and simplicity" in a typeface is pretty much pure subjective opinion. And as for what font to use it's going to depend a lot more on the context of your overall design. This simply can't be answered as-is.

Comment: Ask 50 different designers and you're going to get 50 different answers. This is all merely opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I really recommend Source Sans Pro. It's available on Google Fonts for free.

Other fonts on Google Fonts that I really prefer:

- Montserrat (I like the thick feel of it, especially if all uppercase!)
- Open Sans (Very popular for many webdesigners)
- Droid Sans
- Lato

It's also better for view to make the contrast between your headings and paragraphs higher. By this I mean you would for example make the heading uppercase and bold and the paragraph just normal. This is very efficiënt for reading and makes the viewer pay more attention to it.

This is just my opinion though :D!

[image]

This is how source sans pro looks like

Comment: Hi blagbalabal, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. However, questions like this one are too opinion based and will likely be closed. That doesn't make your answer invalid, but you might flag similar questions in the future :) If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!